# When I cut-paste from a terminal to Jira, each line is followed by a blank line. How can I avoid these blank lines?

Tags: terminal, jira, cut-and-paste

When I cut-paste from a terminal to Jira, each line is followed by a blank line.
**How can I avoid these blank lines appearing when pasting?**

For instance, these are the lines in the terminal:

- List on terminal

[image: list on termina]

And this is how it looked once pasted into Jira:

- List in a Jira comment, paste as is

[image: list in a Jira comment, paste as is]

- List in a Jira comment, as a code snippet

[image: list in a Jira comment, as a code snippet]